# response.status code is Undefined while using an API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, http-status-codes

While using an API I am getting `undefined` rather then the status code like 200 or 404.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    const url = ''; //The API key

    https.get(url, function(response){

        console.log(response.statuscode);
    });
    res.send('App is running');
});
```

Comment: Flagging as caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be :  `response.statusCode`

```
const req = https.request(options, (response) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', response.statusCode);
});
```